# AmCharts stacking issue

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

For some reason value_2 covers value_1 at 2:00
if you hide the value_2 legend, you can see value_1 column.

How do I stack them automatically and display tooltips for both?
If I swap the order of data, the tooltip shows for both values at 2:00 but
value_2 still covers value_1.

Please help

```
am4core.ready(function() {

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
  
  chart.scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();

  chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
  chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;

  chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
  function createSeries(field, color) {
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series.dataFields.valueY = field;
    series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
    series.strokeWidth = 0;

    series.fill = am4core.color(color);
    series.clustered = false;
    series.minBulletDistance = -1;

    series.name = field;
    series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
    series.stacked = true;

    chart.scrollbarX.series.push(series);

    return series;
  }

// Create axes
  var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
  valueAxis.min = 0;

  var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
  dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;
  dateAxis.baseInterval = {
    "timeUnit": 'hour',
    "count": 1
  };

  createSeries('value_1', '#646464');
  createSeries('value_2', '#333333');
  
  chart.data = [
    {
      "date": new Date(2021, 5, 4, 1),
      "value_1": 2
    },
    {
      "date": new Date(2021, 5, 4, 2),
      "value_1": 2,
    },
    {
      "date": new Date(2021, 5, 4, 2),
      "value_2": 9,
    },
  ];

}); // end am4core.ready()
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/tengotengo/pen/NWjOVbe)

Answer (score 1):

Your data needs to be grouped by date; separating them out as individual elements will cause visual glitches like in your codepen.

```
  chart.data = [
    {
      date: new Date(2021, 5, 4, 1),
      value_1: 2
    },
    {
      date: new Date(2021, 5, 4, 2),
      value_1: 2,
      value_2: 9
    }
  ];
```